# Argument userId: Got invalid value '5106220' on Prisma.findManyTodos. Provided String, expected IntFilter or Int:

Tags: next.js, prisma, next-auth

using next.js +next-auth +  Prisma + PostgreSQL
I added a custom login page and added the providers as well.
my userId in the database is Int so when I log in with credentials I have no issue but when logging in with one of the social providers I get an error...

```
Argument userId: Got invalid value '5106220' on Prisma.findManyTodos. Provided String, expected IntFilter or Int:
```

how to force providers to use Int instead of String when connecting to a database.
This error occurs whenever i need to connect the database
This is a Full error

```
provider: {
id: 'facebook',
name: 'Facebook',
type: 'oauth',
authorization: {
  url: 'https://www.facebook.com/v11.0/dialog/oauth',
  params: [Object]
},
token: {
  url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token',
  params: {}
},
userinfo: {
  url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/me',
  params: [Object],
  request: [AsyncFunction: request]
},
profile: [Function: profile],
idToken: false,
checks: [ 'state' ],
clientId: 'MyClientId',
clientSecret: '413db228b5b8e2e1134f5',
signinUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin/facebook',
callbackUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/facebook'


 }
}

[next-auth][debug][PROFILE_DATA] {
  OAuthProfile: {
    id: '11062270',
    name: 'obi ',
    email: 'ow1@gmail.com',
    picture: { data: [Object] }
  }
}
[next-auth][debug][OAUTH_CALLBACK_RESPONSE] {
  profile: {
    id: '5062260',
    name: ' Eco',
    email: 'ow1@gmail.com',
    image: 'https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=570&height=50&width=50&e&hash=AeR6hTT03RbzF9Z9hkg'
  },
  account: {
    provider: 'facebook',
    type: 'oauth',
    providerAccountId: '0711062270',
    access_token: 'EAAVmjxtUcOMBACPeAQm3Ocb0zzKcl8uiZAnZCYhhYxGo',
    token_type: 'bearer',
    expires_at: 1669548134
  },
  OAuthProfile: {
    id: '560',
    name: 'co',
    email: 'ow1@gmail.com',
    picture: { data: [Object] }
  }
}
{
  user: {
    name: 'co',
    email: 'ow1@gmail.com',
    image: 'https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=5007110622680570&height=50&width=50&ext=1666977090&hash=AeR6hTT03RbzF9Z9hkg',
    id: '106226'
  },
  expires: '2022-10-28T17:11:31.515Z',
  id: '1062'
}
PrismaClientValidationError: 
Invalid `prisma.todos.findMany()` invocation:

{
  where: {
    userId: '7110620'
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  },
  select: {
    id: true,
    text: true,
    done: true
  }
}

Argument userId: Got invalid value '5106220' on prisma.findManyTodos. Provided String, expected IntFilter or Int:
type IntFilter {
  equals?: Int
  in?: List<Int>
  notIn?: List<Int>
  lt?: Int
  lte?: Int
  gt?: Int
  gte?: Int
  not?: Int | NestedIntFilter
}
type IntFilter {
  equals?: Int
  in?: List<Int>
  notIn?: List<Int>
  lt?: Int
  lte?: Int
  gt?: Int
  gte?: Int
  not?: Int | NestedIntFilter
}


    at Document.validate (C:\Users\elear\Desktop\TokTok4u\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:29297:20)
    at serializationFn (C:\Users\elear\Desktop\TokTok4u\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:31876:19)
    at runInChildSpan (C:\Users\elear\Desktop\TokTok4u\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:25100:12)
    at PrismaClient._executeRequest (C:\Users\elear\Desktop\TokTok4u\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:31883:31)
    at consumer (C:\Users\elear\Desktop\TokTok4u\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:31810:23)
    at C:\Users\elear\Desktop\TokTok4u\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:31815:51
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:201:9)
    at C:\Users\elear\Desktop\TokTok4u\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:31815:29
    at runInChildSpan (C:\Users\elear\Desktop\TokTok4u\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:25100:12)
    at PrismaClient._request (C:\Users\elear\Desktop\TokTok4u\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:31812:22) {
  clientVersion: '4.4.0'
}
API resolved without sending a response for /api/v1/todo/get, this may result in stalled requests.
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add **+** before the field.

Example **+id** or **+productId** and try again.

This helps me resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Prisma adapter in the NextAuth docs](https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/prisma), the `User` model in the Prisma schema needs to have an `id` field with a `String` type.

Comment: I know there are aspects here and there in using INT VS STRING.
But my application is in an advanced state and it is built on id as Int.
So I'm looking if it's possible to maybe convert to id before prismaClient Only the social providers

Comment: [this page](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema) * ` explains the prisma.schema with id Int`

Answer (score 0):

*Changing only schema is not enough*, **solution should be to [make your own adapter](https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/creating-a-database-adapter)**. `@next-auth/prisma-adapter` uses default Next-Auth's [model](https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/models) & [schema](https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/prisma#create-the-prisma-schema), which declare `id` as a `string` type. This means that native adapter expects you to follow them and thus, types them as such and don't convert provided strings as integers. Here you can check the structure of the native [adapter](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/blob/main/packages/adapter-prisma/src/index.ts#L223).

## How I solved it

```js
export function CustomAdapter(client) {
  return {
    createUser: (data) => client.user.create({
      data
    }),
    getUser: (id) =>
      client.user.findUnique({
        where: {
          id: typeof id === "number" ? id : Number.parseInt(id)
        },
      }),
    /** ... rest of the functions */
  }
}
```

If you are using **TypeScript** you will have quite a time, it's really painful to correctly type everything due to how strongly typed `DefaultAdapter` is. Types you would need to look in to are `Adapter`, `AdapterUser` and `AdapterAccount`, all of which is inside `next-auth/adapters.d.ts`